# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) for my custom packages

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to use two custom packages in my worklight application and using dojoConfig to use them. Below is the Script code that I am using. Problem is that I am getting error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) -
 http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:10080/js/controllers/HomeController.js" when my app is trying to access the packages. I have created the js file and the absolute path of it is "StoreLocator_Proj/apps/StoreLocator_App/common/js/controllers/HomeController.js". Can anyone please help me what could be the reason of this error ? Am I doing anything wrong in baseUrl ?

```
    <script>
        dojoConfig = {
         baseUrl: "/js/",
         tlmSiblingOfDojo: false, 
        parseOnLoad: true,
        isDebug:false,
        async:true,
        simulateIpad:true,
        mblAlwaysHideAddressBar: true,
        packages: [
        { name: "controllers" , location: "controllers"},
        { name: "model" , location: "model"}
        ]
        };
        </script>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dojo/dojo.js"
           data-dojo-config="async:true"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, with Dojo in general, the package location is relative upon the location of the hosted Dojo. In this example it would mean that it would look for your modules at:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/controllers/
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/model/
```

Because you're working with a CDN.  If you want to work with custom packages, then you should probably define the hostname in your `location` property as suggested by [this article](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/cdn/) on Dojo.

---

For Worklight it will probably be a bit different, but I assume that the cause is quite similar. Because you're referencing to a CDN hosted Dojo, it will "miss" a part of the relative path. To fix this I suggest using a local version of Dojo. For example:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    dojoConfig = {
        isDebug: false,
        async: true,
        mblAlwaysHideAddressBar: true,
        simulateIpad: true,
        packages : [ {
            name : "controller",
            location : "/js/controller"
        } ]
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Dimitri, I added "location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, '') +" in the location as per your suggested article and it is working fine now.